# What's the fastest way to transfer from Terminal 2D to terminal 2E (M gates) in CDG airport?

Tags: transit, france, short-connections, cdg

I will have a *very* tight transfer soon between a Schengen flight to 2D and a non-Schengen flight from terminal 2E, M gates. For certain reasons I'd rather not miss it, even if it means I'm guaranteed a free hotel stay (as the next flight is in 24 hours) and a 600EUR compensation.

What's the fastest way to transfer between the two parts of the airport? If it matters I'm a fast runner with a very small carry on. Looking at the map I can see two options:

- Walk to terminal 2F, then to terminal 2E, then take the tram to M gates
- Take the "blue route" bus from 2D, which eventually stops at the M gates

Or perhaps I'm unnecessarily worried and an Air France representative would meet me at the arrival gate if my flight is delayed?

Comment: From my experience, the airline will always try to get you on your next flight if you've booked on the same ticket, because rebooking and compensation can get very expensive.

Comment: @gparyani That, and there is even a special border control booth located next to the tarmac for those needing special transport between airplanes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Follow the "Correspondances" signs, and for terminal 2E whenever it's shown.
2. Clear immigration.
3. Keep following the signs for terminal 2E
4. Take the sterile bus to terminal 2E. The M gates are two stops away

Of course, if you know the incoming flight will be delayed, speak to the cabin crew, show your connecting boarding pass and they may be able to arrange transport. Once at CDG (where I entered Schengen) they even stopped at a special border control booth located outside, where the police glanced at my ID card for a second before letting us on.