# Is there a way to quickly transfer between terminals 2E and 2D at CDG?

Tags: transit, cdg

I've transferred from a non-Schengen flight in terminal 2E to a Schengen flight at terminal 2D last week and was very surprised by the inefficiency of the whole process:

- First there's a security check for people who transfer to other terminals
- Then you have to take the bus to a different terminal and since 2D is just one stop behind 2E, you essentially have to drive through every stop at CDG before you can get to 2D
- At 2D there's passport control as expected, but then your only option is to exit to the public area instead of transferring to your gate
- Since you've exited to the public area there's now a second security check you have to do

Is there a faster way to do the same transfer? I will fly again on this route soon and would prefer to find a better route. 2D to 2E is only 20 minutes, while the other way around took me 1 hour, so I hope a better path exists.

Note that this isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107114/whats-the-fastest-way-to-transfer-from-terminal-2d-to-terminal-2e-m-gates-in) as in this case the transfer is the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you arrived at L gates. Then the alternatives are:

- take the people mover to the 2E main building
- go through immigration and customs
- take bus N1 to 2D (supposedly 17 minutes, every 8 minutes)
- go through security

Or:

- take the people mover to the 2E main building
- go through immigration and customs
- walk: take a left, go up, walk to the train station, go the opposite corner, walk to 2D
- go through security

Answer (score 1):

I remember doing this, both ways, some time ago. Non-Schengen to Schengen is clumsy, as you need to go through everything. Passport control, customs, and security again.

The only thing you can speed up is 2E to 2D. I remember walking, and it took me 15 minutes, give or take.

On the way back, 2D to 2E was easy. Walk inside the secure area, no security check, and passport control only to exit Schengen.

Comment: Is there a way to take the bus in the other direction at CDG, so that you don't have to cruise all around the airport for just one stop? Also, skipping the second security check would save at least 15 minutes.

Comment: Nope. There's only one way. And since you enter Schengen, you need to pass through customs, and go back through security.

Comment: Or perhaps it would be faster to just exit to the public level at 2E and take the public bus between terminals? That way you'd at least skip the first security check.

Comment: Walking, unless you have lots of luggage, is probably the fastest.

Comment: If you’ve booked a through ticket and checked your baggage through to your final destination, http://easycdg.com/passenger-information/connecting-flight-connections-paris-cdg-airport/transfer-terminal-2e/ seems to indicate a 45 minute transfer time, including one security and one passport check