# Tight international transfer at CDG from 2E to 2D, what is the best option?

Tags: international-travel, short-connections, cdg

I am going to have a tight connection (65 min) at Paris-CDG, arriving from the US on AF at terminal 2E, and connecting to UIA departing terminal 2D (non-Schengen).

I have read many posts about the best transfer option, but all of them are talking about transferring from non-Schengen to Schengen flights, which is not my case.

The most popular suggestion (both on this site and other travel forums) seems to be to exit through immigration to the public area in 2E, and use the walkway via the TVG station, then re-enter 2D via immigration again, but as both my flights are international, that sounds odd.

Others do suggest the inter-terminal shuttle bus, but it is being generally described as incredibly slow and inefficient, especially given the short connection time.

Does anyone here have reliable information about the best connection option? (for completion: I'll be traveling in the first week of Sept., arriving CDG around mid-day)

Many thanks in advance!

p.s. the connection is a valid one-itinerary bought on Delta, luggage will be checked through to de final destination

Comment: Are all the legs on one ticket?

Comment: @MusoniusRufus Yes, just edited the question to include that information

Comment: No need to agonize over something over which you have little to no control. If your connection is tight they will have staff transport you and hold the departing flight as long as practical. They **typically** won't let your bags travel without you on the flight. They would have to remove them, and that takes time. Enough time for you to have caught the UIA flight.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus, Well my question is not about whether or not the connection is viable, rather, I am asking for advice about the most efficient and practical transfer route to use.

Comment: See also: [http://easycdg.com/passenger-information/connecting-flight-connections-paris-cdg-airport/transfer-terminal-2e/](http://easycdg.com/passenger-information/connecting-flight-connections-paris-cdg-airport/transfer-terminal-2e/)

Comment: Just adding the usual comment about short connections: you may make it, but your luggage may not. Be prepared for that possibility. Also, if your incoming flight is late and they can't hold the departing flight for you, and the next available flight is the next day, you may have to stay overnight in Paris. Be prepare for that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual advice is they wouldn't have sold you the ticket if they thought you couldn't make the transfer.  However, if you let the cabin crew on your flight from the US know that you have a short connection in Paris, they might be able to prioritise your disembarkation.

Once one the ground, your luggage is checked through so no need to worry about that.  Just follow the signs for transfers.  I think you will need to use the shuttle bus to get to 2D.  According to the page on the CDG website (https://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/access/paris-charles-de-gaulle/inter-terminal-shuttles), the shuttle you will need is the Blue Shuttle, though the site doesn't seem to have a timetable.

edit: Indeed, this other page on the CDG website  (https://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/flights/connecting-flights) says pretty much the same thing.

Note, this is not the N1 shuttle mentioned in [Is there a way to quickly transfer between terminals 2E and 2D at CDG?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115546/is-there-a-way-to-quickly-transfer-between-terminals-2e-and-2d-at-cdg?rq=1) which seems to describe a particularly difficult transfer.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information!
any estimation about how long is the bus ride? if I have a measure for that, I would mark your answer as accepted. thanks in advance

Comment: @ISAE, sorry no idea how long, but it will depend on which pier you arrive at because the blue shuttle makes 3 stops in 2E.  You have a through ticket and UIA are a codeshare airline with AF.  It is the airlines responsibility to deal with it if you miss your connection through their failure, and that can involve booking you on a new flight, paying for a hotel, meals, compensation and so on - something they really want to avoid.  It is therefore in their interest to only sell you a routing that is possible.  So they think it is possible to do the transfer in 65 mins if you follow the signs.

Answer (score 4):

I have just returned from that trip, and i would like to share my actual experience here, for the benefit of future readers.

Our flight from the US arrived on time - (we landed 20 min. before schedule actually, but it took us about that amount of time to taxi to the gate...)

It took me 15 min. from the gate to the bus & 23 min. the entire bus ride from 2E - L gates to 2D. (the bus was waiting at the pickup stop as i arrived there, so i cannot say about waiting time for the bus). and i made the connection alright - arrived at the gate about 10 min. before boarding started

unfortunately, as jcaron warned in his comment, my luggage didn't make it. it was delivered to my final destination 3 days after my arrival, urgh...